# Which signal in the sensitivity list triggers the process

Tags: vhdl

In VHDL, when simulating a testbench, I have a process and a sensitivity list.
Is it possible to see which signal in the sensitivity list has triggered the process?
I understand that this may be dependent on the tools.
Im using Xilinx ISE. Does the simulator give this information?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `'transaction` attribute in conjunction with `'event` to determine which signals have had a transaction in the current delta cycle:

```vhdl
process(a, b) is
begin
  if a'transaction'event then
    report "Transaction on a";
  end if;

  if b'transaction'event then
    report "Transaction on b";
  end if;
end process;
```

The `'transaction` attribute creates a new signal of type bit that toggles on each transaction. The `'event` attribute on that signal identifies when any transaction has happened on the parent signal.

You can also use `not <signal name>'quiet(0 ns)` to determine which signals from a sensitivity list have had a transaction since the last time step:

```vhdl
process(a, b) is
begin
  if not a'quiet(0 ns) then
    report "Transaction on a";
  end if;

  if not b'quiet(0 ns) then
    report "Transaction on b";
  end if;
end process;
```

The latter may be more useful if you don't want to deal with sequencing of events that happen on different delta cycles.

Comment: Thanks! it seems attributes are the best way of detecting these.

Comment: Your code will (correctly) report whether there has been a transaction on A or B, but mere transactions will not trigger the sensitivity list. Surely,to answer the question, you need: `if a'event then report "Event on a";` etc That is what the questioner is actually asking.

Answer (score 2):

Two VHDL concepts are relevant here:

- **Transaction**: Assignment of a value to a signal at a simulation cycle (time and delta cycle)
- **Event**: Transaction (assignment) which caused the value of a signal to change

So a transaction occurs on the signal at every assign to that signal, but an
even only occurs if that assign actually changes the value of the signal.

VHDL has these related attributes:

- **`S'active`**: Boolean that is TRUE iff transaction occurred in simulation cycle
- **`S'event`**: Boolean that is TRUE iff event occurred in current simulation cycle

A process is resumed at an event of any of the signals in the sensitivity list,
so to determine which signal(s) that caused resumption of the process, this
code can be used:

```
alfa: process (a, b) is
begin
  report "Process alfa was resumed";
  if a'event then
    report "- Event on a";
  end if;
  if b'event then
    report "- Event on b";
  end if;
end process;
```

If `a` or `b` is assigned with the current value, then no even occurs.

However, VHDL has an attribute that can generate a implicit signal which
changes at every transaction, thus effectively converts an transaction to an
event, whereby a process can be resumed:

- **`S'transaction`**: Bit that changes when transaction occurs

A process that is resumed by transaction on `a` or `b` can thus be made with:

```
bravo: process (a'transaction, b'transaction) is
begin
  report "Process bravo was resumed";
  if a'active then
    report "- Transaction on a";
  end if;
  if a'event then
    report "- Event on a";
  end if;
  if b'active then
    report "- Transaction on b";
  end if;
  if b'event then
    report "- Event on b";
  end if;
end process;
```

The behavior can be shown with a test bench process generating stimuli as:

```
process is
begin
  a <= 0;          -- Declared as natural
  b <= 0;          -- --||--
  wait for 1 ns;
  a <= 1;          -- Both transaction and event @ 1 ns 1 delta
  wait for 0 sec;  -- Delta delay
  a <= 1;          -- Only transaction, but no event @ 1 ns 2 delta
  wait for 0 sec;  -- Delta delay
  b <= 2;          -- Both transaction and event @ 1 ns 3 delta
  wait for 0 sec;  -- Delta delay
  a <= 3;          -- Both transaction and event @ 1 ns 4 delta
  b <= 3;          -- Both transaction and event @ 1 ns 4 delta
  wait for 1 ns;
  wait;
end process;
```

This will drive signals as shown below.  Note that ModelSims "Expanded Time
Deltas Mode" has been used to show signal changes during the delta cycles:

[image]

Report output from process alfa (except initial run at 0 ps) is:

```
Time: 1 ns  Iteration: 1  Instance: /tb    # ** Note: Process alfa was resumed
Time: 1 ns  Iteration: 1  Instance: /tb    # ** Note: - Event on a

Time: 1 ns  Iteration: 3  Instance: /tb    # ** Note: Process alfa was resumed
Time: 1 ns  Iteration: 3  Instance: /tb    # ** Note: - Event on b

Time: 1 ns  Iteration: 4  Instance: /tb    # ** Note: Process alfa was resumed
Time: 1 ns  Iteration: 4  Instance: /tb    # ** Note: - Event on a
Time: 1 ns  Iteration: 4  Instance: /tb    # ** Note: - Event on b
```

Report output from process bravo (except initial run at 0 ps) is:

```
Time: 1 ns  Iteration: 1  Instance: /tb    # ** Note: Process bravo was resumed
Time: 1 ns  Iteration: 1  Instance: /tb    # ** Note: - Transaction on a
Time: 1 ns  Iteration: 1  Instance: /tb    # ** Note: - Event on a

Time: 1 ns  Iteration: 2  Instance: /tb    # ** Note: Process bravo was resumed
Time: 1 ns  Iteration: 2  Instance: /tb    # ** Note: - Transaction on a

Time: 1 ns  Iteration: 3  Instance: /tb    # ** Note: Process bravo was resumed
Time: 1 ns  Iteration: 3  Instance: /tb    # ** Note: - Transaction on b
Time: 1 ns  Iteration: 3  Instance: /tb    # ** Note: - Event on b

Time: 1 ns  Iteration: 4  Instance: /tb    # ** Note: Process bravo was resumed
Time: 1 ns  Iteration: 4  Instance: /tb    # ** Note: - Transaction on a
Time: 1 ns  Iteration: 4  Instance: /tb    # ** Note: - Event on a
Time: 1 ns  Iteration: 4  Instance: /tb    # ** Note: - Transaction on b
Time: 1 ns  Iteration: 4  Instance: /tb    # ** Note: - Event on b
```

So, as can be seen, the transaction only signal change for `a` at 1 ns delta 2 is only reported by the transaction check in process bravo, and there is no event associated with
this.

Answer (score 0):

**@Morten, So using events and transaction I can even capture the instance that I send the same value to a signal in succession.
As in the example:**

a <= 0;          -- Declared as natural

b <= 0;
  wait for 1 ns;

a <= 1;          -- Both transaction and event @ 1 ns 1 delta

wait for 0 sec;  -- Delta delay

a <= 1;          -- Only transaction, but no event @ 1 ns 2 delta

wait for 0 sec;  -- Delta delay

**In this line where you assign the same value to signal 'a'**

a <= 1;          -- Only transaction, but no event @ 1 ns 2 delta

My assumption is that you can capture this instance where transaction=1, event=0.

This is great, however, when synthesized in FPGA would this still be the case?

Comment: Transaction only (no value change) and `wait for 0 sec` are only for use in simulation, since hardware needs changes in signal for any communication to occur (thus not transaction only), and there is no such concept of delta cycles (`wait for 0 sec`) in hardware.

Comment: Thanks for the replies and clarification. Much appreciated.