# Which specific signal in the sensitivity list triggers a process in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, hdl

I am doing a project in **VHDL** and I am stuck at this point. Any help is appreciated.
The problem is described as follows:
I have a 2D array with N (in number) std_logic_vector signals. The number N is defined in generics, so we do not know the specific length of the array (we use N instead).
This array is used as sensitivity list of a process in order to trigger it. Like so: `process(arrayOfSignals)`

**My question is:** Is there any way to know which specific signal of the array triggered the process? (Like for example the signal: **arrayOfSignals(2)**)

I have seen this post: [Which signal in the sensitivity list triggers the process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770387/which-signal-in-the-sensitivity-list-triggers-the-process)  but it is not the case here. It would be the case if all the signals of their sensitivity list where inside an array, and this array was triggering the process.

To become clear, below is the VHDL code of what I am trying to do.

```
process(arrayOfSignals)
    begin
    for i in 0 to N-1 loop
        if arrayOfSignals(i)'transaction'event then --I want to determine which signal of arrayOfSignals (position in the array) triggerd the process.
         case arrayOfSignals(i) is
             when "01" =>
                 AD(i)(30 downto 23) <= AD(i)(7 downto 0);
                 exit;
             when others => null; exit;
         end case;
         exit;
        end if;
    end loop;
    end process;
```

Comment: First of all, what is the end goal here? none of the code is synthesisable and cannot be converted to logic. Is it your intention that this is only simulation code?

Comment: Given your explanation - `'transaction'event` should do what you are looking for. A process is triggered by a `'event` on any signal in the sensitivity list, so any change on any bit in the `arrayOfSignals` signal will trigger the process, and you can use `'transaction'event` to discover which ones have had an event occur.

Comment: The -  `arrayOfSignals'transaction'event` returns True if any signal in the whole array triggers the process. In my case I want to find the specific signal in the array that triggers the process. The `arrayOfSignals(i)'transaction'event` doesn't work, but I wrote it above in order to show you what I want to do.

Comment: The above should work.  Can you describe how its not working and what tool etc?

Comment: I am using vivado. The `arrayOfSignals(i)'transaction'event` is underlined as an error, thats why it does not work. The error in simple words says that the `'transaction'event` attribute must used only on static values and not on indexed values.

Comment: Yes, you're correct (I had forgotten about static naming rules). For this, you're probably going to need a generate loop so you can put each `arrayOfSignals(i)` in its own process so you can detect the `event`. But you still havent explained the context. What you are doing seems far more complex than it likely needs to be.

Comment: Well, this is a subproject of a bigger project that we are working on, in my university. In this part, I was given a VHDL file that had 6 ports in total. Every port was of type std_logi_vector. 
What I am supposed to do is to generalize it, in order to be used with N ports (declared in the generics).
Now, the initial file had 6 processes (one for each port) that were triggered when there was a change at the port that were responsible for. To become clear, the process1 had only the 1st port as sensitivity list, the process2 had the 2nd port, etc.

Comment: Since I had to generalize it, firstly I made an array of std_logic_vectors as a port (which I am not sure if is legal for synthesis). Secondly, I wanted to convert the logic for every process. So, I made one process that had that array as sensitivity list and then I had to find which signal (port) had changed, in order to execute the appropriate lines of code. 
I hope it explains the context.

Comment: But why do you need to know which changed? why cant you simply apply all the outputs on ALL ports every time anything changes? Have you got a circuit diagram of the expected circuit? Your code looks like a software program, but I suspect you're trying to describe hardware. You should know the circuit before attempting to write code.

Comment: The change should be applyed only when the corresponding signal changed its value. Also, the change that should be done is different for every case (The code above is a sample, not the whole program). So, I should not apply all the changes.

Comment: I think I found a solution to that. I used the `'last_value` attribute which returns the previous value of one signal (before the change). This way, I compare all the curernt values of the array with the previous ones and I should get the required result.
The problem now is, if all this is synthesizable. Because, I read here: https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2019_2/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf 
 that I cannot use arrays of std_logic_vector as ports. Although, at another post here they say that it can be done even in VHDL93.

Comment: Please excuse me if I say anything wrong, it is because I do my first steps in hardware.

Comment: Use of attributes like this is not synthesisable and not going to produce hardware. Also, the use of loops and exit are generally not recommended until you understand the hardware implications. Have you created a circuit diagram of the logic circuit you intended to create? The code you have posted implies you have software programming knowledge - HDLs require you to forget what you know about programming and learn digital logic instead. HDLs written in a software style will result in code that yields poor hardware or just wont compile at all.

Comment: Well, I understand that it does not make too much sense to have an array of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR as a port in a chip, and I would have avoid using it if there were any alternative way. But since I have to create a chip with unknown number of ports, (defined in the generics) I created an array that includes all of them. It makes sense from software perspective but as you confirmed, it is a problem in hardware. Now that I know that it is not synthesizable, I am stuck for sure. I will ask for more details because we work on that as a team in my university and will come back to discuss on new base.

Comment: Thanks for the information, you were very helpful. Excuse again my poor knowledge on hardware programming logic.

Comment: Arrays of std_logic_vector are very common.  As are an unknown number of them.  But your code is rather unique.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do exactly what you are asking. But let me suggest a way to do what I think you are trying to do.
Typically if you want to detect a change in a signal, you would have a clocked process and make a registered copy of the signal. You can then compare the state of your input signal with your registered copy (for each element) and if they are not equal, the input has changed and you can trigger your logic.